# Обособление приложений

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно обособить приложения в следующем предложении?

Основанием для разработки послужило известное преимущество данного типа трубопроводной арматуры, затвора дискового поворотного в сравнении с другими типами трубопроводной арматуры, где при одинаковых условных диаметрах DN, условных давлениях PN и прочих равных данных (,) затвор имеет меньшие габаритные размеры и вес, что выгодно отражается на себестоимости.

Я думаю, что нужно тире, но не знаю, нужна ли в таком случае запятая после "поворотного"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно предложить следующий вариант:

Основанием для разработки послужило известное преимущество данного типа трубопроводной арматуры - затвора дискового поворотного -  в сравнении с другими вариантами, где при одинаковых условных диаметрах DN, условных давлениях PN и прочих равных данных  затвор имеет меньшие габаритные размеры и вес, что выгодно отражается на себестоимости.

Приложение можно обособить и запятыми, но в данном предложении и так много запятых.

Comment: Т.е. можно обособить и запятыми? Потому что я думала, что если можно вставить "а именно", то обязательно употребляется тире.

Comment: При пояснительном значении  приложения как раз основной формой является обособление ЗАПЯТЫМИ,  а тире придает  сообщению  добавочный, присоединительный характер (это авторский вариант).

Comment: Примеры: "Лёгкие судороги –  признак сильного волнения –  пробежали по его щекам.Рязанцев и Зоя –  его жена – были из одного класса. Рыбак – типичный севастопольский старик с худым от ветра лицом – сидел на земле и латал рваную сеть".   На  выбор тире при обособлении приложений влияют такие  факторы  как добавочный характер сообщения или его  распространенность.

Comment: А такие приложения оформлены правильно? И равных мужчинам — композиторам и поэтам — среди женщин пока что нет. (знаю, что фраза спорная)

Comment: И равных мужчинам — композиторам и поэтам  среди женщин пока что нет.
Второе тире опускается, если приложение выражает более конкретное значение.